# JQuery bind event to collection item

Tags: jquery

I am able to bind events to all elements of a collection using JQuery. Anyway, if I want to pick just one item of the collection, no event is bound to it. In the upcoming code snippet there must be a mistake. Thanks in advance!

```
var divs = jQuery('.elternklasse').get(0).bind('click', function(){
    alert('Bin da');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eq()`:

```
var divs = jQuery('.elternklasse').eq(0).bind('click', function(){
    alert('Bin da');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4n2ab/).

To attach to an event to a specific range of elements, you could use `:gt()` or `:lt()`:

```
var divs = $('div:gt(3)').bind('click', function(){
    alert('Bin da');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4n2ab/2/).

```
var divs = $('div:lt(3)').bind('click', function(){
    alert('Bin da');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4n2ab/3/).

Or to attach events to an arbitrary range of elements between two known points in the array of elements, use `slice()`:

```
var divs = $('div').slice(3,6).bind('click', function(){
    alert('Bin da');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4n2ab/4/).

The above will trigger the click event on elements from index-point 3 until, but *not including*, 6.

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`:gt()` greater-than selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).
- [`:lt()` less-than selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).
- [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Answer (score 0):

The `.get()` function returns the actual DOM element, not a jQuery object, so you can't call jQuery functions on it. You'll need to use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function instead, which will reduce the set to only the element at that position.